# How to organise the correct handling of versions of binaries

Tags: git, devops, build-system, jenkins, technology

I'm currently working in a firm, based on an executable, who uses different DLLs. There are several issues:

- Everybody builds the binaries on his own PC.
- The executables (`*.exe` and `*.dll` files) are not (as I call it) *signed*.

*Signed? What is that?*
I mean that, from the executable file, it is impossible to retrieve the GIT version that has been used in order to build that executable.

On StackOverflow, I have already asked some questions about how to add a signature to an executable, using `[assembly]` items in the Visual Studio project, using `dotnet-gitversion` for adding, amongst others, the ShortSHA of the GIT commit.
I have also started installing `Jenkins` in my PC, in order to have an idea on how to create a build server.

One of my colleagues does not talk in terms of individual features, but in entire packages/technologies/frameworks/..., and he asked me "*Are you talking about DevOps? There are entire packages and tools for that, and everything is on the cloud*".

My first reaction was like "*Hold your horses, I'm just interested in adding signatures to executables and the usage of a build server*", but I must admit he has a point: why going through so much trouble for implementing and developing individual features myself if there are entire packages that are doing this for me?

So hereby my question: what way of working covers both the usage of build servers and the (as I call it) "signing" of executables?

Thanks in advance

Comment: ... and why has my question been closed? I'm just asking how to organise my building and delivery process, not bottom-up, but top-down. What's wrong with that?

Comment: tools recommendations are off-topic here, sorry. See [help/on-topic]

Comment: "So hereby my question: **what technology/package/framework/...** covers both the usage of build servers and the "signing" of executables?" — this text explicitly asks for a tool. Despite the title being "how to organize" it is difficult to see how you are *not* asking for a tool recommendation. Could you reword the question and remove the request for a tool?

Comment: @GregBurghardt: I've updated my question, now it's only about ways of working anymore, no tools are requested. Is that ok?

Comment: I voted to reopen the question, even though I still feel like it is too broad. Can you define more what you mean by "ways of working"? It is still a little difficult to see what the question is really about.

Comment: The question title also mentions "handling versions of binaries" but the question text talks about signing binaries. Those are two different things. The question title sounds like "dependency management" but signing binaries is more about security than dependency management.

Comment: It's ok to have multiple questions. But it's not helpful to cram them all into one post. If you think they're related feel free to link them to each other. But give us a question with a clear singular subject and you'll get better answers.

Comment: @GregBurghardt: thanks for the term "Dependency management", I've never heard of that. However I don't get what you mean with the signing of binaries being related to security, how is that? (You know that by signing binaries, I just mean adding the GIT hash to the binary file's details, in order to get the link with the correct version of the source code. How does this relate to security?

Comment: @Dominique, if all you are doing is trying to link a binary to source code, signing is not what you after looking for either. Signing a binary and checking that signature before importing it ensures nothing has altered the binary. Presumably if the binary was altered unexpectedly then a computer virus, worm, trojan or some other infection changed it. You might be looking for software versioning schemes, like [semver](https://semver.org/).

Comment: Do you have a source for this: "You know that by signing binaries, I just mean adding the GIT hash to the binary file's details"? I think you have misunderstood what signing is. The tool, dotnet-gitversion, you mention is about, well, versioning. Signing usually means **code signing**, see e.g. here for more details: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_signing

Comment: @TomG: thanks, but I'm aware of this. By signing I mean "adding some kind of signature", like on paper. I'm not talking about possible security issues.

Comment: @TomG: nevertheless, I see your point and I've, as much as possible, replaced the term "signing an executable" by "adding a signature to an executable".

Comment: What's the point of the signature on the paper? It is to vouch for the thing you are signing. In the case of binaries, that **is** code signing. As @GregBurghardt said, you are probably looking for version, e.g. semver.

Comment: @TomG: I do understand the advantages of semver, but it also means that you must have an automatic version update system in order to link an executable with a source code version. When you add the commit hash (or the ShortSha) to your executable, there's no need for such an automatic version update system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general the term "continuous integration" covers workflows which revolve around build servers. But you don't necessarily need this if you just want to put the commit hash into the binary. You've not said which language you're working in but it might be C#, in which case https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15141338/embed-git-commit-hash-in-a-net-dll may help?

In general the solution will look similar.

- add a step to the automated build process (make, cmake, msbuild etc) to get the current commit hash
- write that into a source or metadata file *before* the build

Adding things to an executable *after* it's built is generally painful and should be avoided as much as possible. Unless it's an actual signature using the signing tools.